# Execute shortcodes in excerpts

Tags: jquery

I need a JQuery help..

i have populated checkboxes as follows

```
<span class="checked">
 <input class="cbid" type="checkbox" name="cb1">
</span>
<span >
  <input class="cbid" type="checkbox" name="cb2">
</span>
<span class="checked">
  <input class="cbid" type="checkbox" name="cb3">
</span>
```

i need to make an array using the value of name attribute of checkboxes where their parent's(span) class is 'checked'

e.g.

["cb1","cb3"]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var names = $('.checked > :checkbox').map(function() {
    return this.name;
}).toArray();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LgFak/)

Using a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in conjunction with the [child selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and the jQuery (Sizzle) [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector (which is equivalent to `[type=checkbox]`).

[`$().map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a jQuery object, hence the [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) at the end. This is just one of the many ways to achieve the requested result.